# Angular 2 Quickstart - where the files

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm pretty new to Angular 2 and I just started to learn it. After doing this: 
npm install -g angular-cli - I couldn't find on the hard drive this folder: src/app / ./src/app/app.component.ts.

My question is - in order to open the files in notepad++ - how can I locate it on my hard drive? I looked in program files / nodejs but it wasn't there

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`npm install -g angular-cli` has installed the angular command line.
You don't have any created project yet.

What you need to do next is run the following commands:

```
ng new your-app-name // create the app with angular-cli
cd your-app-name // change directory to your new angular app
ng serve // run your new angular app
```

Check the official site here: https://cli.angular.io/

Comment: Hi Martin. Thanks for your answer. However, I did create a new project (by following the quickstart tutorial (https://angular.io/guide/quickstart ) , and I do can access the folder through the command line - cd. However, my question was - how do I access it on the hard drive? In other words - where's the link between the cmd and the hard drive? Meaning, if I want want to open the file on notepad++ for example, how do I access it outside the cmd? It's mean - where is it on the hard drive? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi. I think I understand now. The location of your application depends on the location where you executed `ng new your-app`.
Let's suppose that you execute the command in your C:\. 
The "your-app" folder containing your app files will be located in C:\your-app. 
Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I've found it. Now things are clear. Thanks for your help. Working with the CMD feels like taking a time machine to the 80's when I used to write with pascal and QBasic on DOS ...

Comment: ajajaj ok! I'm glad I could help you